# How to get an entire function $f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ is an entire function such that $|zf(z)-1+e^z|\leq 1+|z| \ \forall z\in \mathbb C$ then which of the folowing are true?

(1) $f'(0)=1$,

(2) $f'(0)=-1/2$,

(3) $f'(0)=-1/3$,

(4) $f'(0)= -1/4 $

My approach:

Since $f$ is an entire function so it has a power series expansion then $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$.

So, $|z\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n-1+e^z|=|z\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}|=|a_0z+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_nz+\frac{1}{n!})z^n|$

So, $|a_0z+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_nz+\frac{1}{n!})z^n|\leq 1+|z|$

Now I can not understand how to proceed. Can anyone please help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show that $zf(z)-1+e^z$ must be a linear function? Then note that $zf(z)-1+e^z$ is $$
zf(0) + z^2 f'(0) + O(z^3 ) - 1 + 1 + z + \frac{{z^2 }}{2} + O(z^3 ) = z(f(0) + 1) + \left( {f'(0) + \frac{1}{2}} \right)z^2  + O(z^3 )
$$ as $z\to 0$.

Comment: @Gary from the last inequality we get $f(z)$ is linear. Is not? Like $f(z)$ is of the form $(f(0)+1)z$.

Comment: First you show that $zf(z)-1+e^z$ is linear ($f(z)$ is not linear). Then use the expansion I gave to compute $f'(0)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g(z)=zf(z)-1+e^z$. Then you always have $|g(z)|\leqslant1+|z|$, and [therefore](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2418785/446262) $g(z)=az+b$ for some numbers $a,b\in\Bbb C$. But\begin{align}zf(z)-1+e^z=az+b&\iff zf(z)=az+b+1-e^z\\&\iff f(z)=a+\frac{b+1-e^z}z.\end{align}Since $f$ is entire, it has no pole at $0$, and so $b+1-e^0=0$; in other words, $b=0$. So,$$z\ne0\implies f(z)=a-\frac{e^z-1}z.$$But then$$f(z)=a-1-\frac z2-\frac{z^2}6+\cdots,$$and therefore $f'(0)=-\frac12$.